# Animations don't load on browser

Tags: google-chrome, opera

Why do certain parts of webpages don't run on my computer?
For example the [first link on the MSU page](http://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/VirtTxtJml/alhalrx2.htm#hal4).More specifically ,[this applet](http://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/VirtTxtJml/sn2mov.htm).

I have running it on my chrome, opera and citroen.Does it have to do anything with Java?

Or can nobody run these on their pc (maybe because of some problem with the website)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the page codes on Chrome and Edge and simply there was no applet on that page.

Many of these scientific websites had been using Java applets. I believe that for many security concerns, browsers have been blocking Java plugin, and therefore old applets from running. Eventually, web masters stopped embedding them or they are being upgraded.

Comment: Chrome and other similar browsers don;t support NPAPI (since Sept 1 2015).I installed an extension called IE Tab from the chrome web store(since Internet Explorer still supports Java and NPAPI).Now all animations run smoothly :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)